# If weak force causes decay of a single particle, why is it called a force between two particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, weak-interaction, electroweak

Weak force acts at very short distances (`10^-16 to 10^-17 m`), but what is this distance ? Is this the distance between two particles that can experience this force ? But the effect of a weak force is that a single particle decays.. so what is the meaning of this distance ?

Also, colloquially, force is something that affects two objects (gravity, strong and electromagnetic forces satisfy this colloquial sense). So, when we call a decay of particles, as the weak force, are we not using this colloquial sense of the word '`force`', but instead relying on the sense of a force being '`interactions`' of that particle ?

Answer (score 1):

On the level of subatomic particles, forces are better understood as possible interaction channels through which states can exchange energy. The analogy with a force "pushing" on something is completely lost, so your second supposition is the right one.

The distance you are referring to is about how close two particles need to be for having a significant odd of interacting via the weak force. That is what is meant by the distance of the interaction. This small distance is directly related to the fact that the bosons mediating the weak force are massive, unlike photons.

Comment: Which are the two particles coming together, since weak interactions only occur when a *single* particle decays ?

Comment: @Daud In the case of, let's suppose, a free neutron decay, than that distance could be understood, at the smallest order, as the mean distance the W boson involved travels before decaying into the product particle, (electron and neutrino).